# Inequality within complex

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, examples-counterexamples, absolute-value

I step with a inequality and would like to know if it is truth...

$||(a_1-a_2)^2+i(b_1-b_2)^2||\leq ||a_1^2+ib_1^2||+||a_2^2+ib_2^2||,\quad \forall a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to prove it but couldn't. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong.

Try $a_1=b_1=1$ and $a_2=b_2=-1$.